Vocabulary question: usage of 推考
I ran across the following passage:
しかし、この集はまた実によくできていて、『奥の細道』にも十分に匹敵する文芸作品となっている。これは、集内の句を別にすれば芭蕉が『奥の細道』以後も、詞書などの句文等に推考しておいたためである。
(full text here)
My problem came up with the sentence in bold (the previous sentence is for context). I think the verb is what's throwing me off.
So according to Jisho, 推考　means "surmise, speculate". The japanese dicctionaries I consulted give it as "物事の道理や事情などを推測して考えること", so they agree with jisho.
But then...
What's being speculated? Who's doing the speculation? is Bashō speculating about his poems and prose? why is 句文等 marked with に　and what kind of relation does have with 推考?
The "conhjecture speculate" meaning doesn't make much sense to me here. Which leads me to think some other nuance of this compund must be at work, but so far I haven't found many examples/alternative definitions.

It could be a typo for 推敲. It still doesn't make much sense to me, though.

I'm just Japanese native speaker, not linguistic professional.
I think it's typo for 推敲 as @aguijonazo mentioned.
About the meaing, I think what this sentense means is that 芭蕉 refined his 詞書 after he wrote the poems and returned from the travels. Haiku often comes with 詞書. The meaning of 詞書 is below(Sorry I just translate the description in dictionary with deepL). I think "集内の句を別にすれば " emphasize that he didn't refine his 俳句 itself onece after he created it.

詞書(コトバガキ) is a preface to a waka or haiku that describes the motive, subject matter, and circumstances of its formation.
https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%A9%9E%E6%9B%B8-65560

Though The sentence seems to lack words for me too.
If this is 「詞書などの句文等を推考しておいたためである。」, it seems more natural for me.
